# `:hover` and `mouseenter` event failed when no `background-color` is set in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

The related style rules look like this:

```
    .name {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        width: 220px;
        text-indent: 24px;
        *margin-left: -24px;
        background: rgba(198, 211, 205, 0.5);   
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50c6d3cd,endColorstr=#50c6d3cd);
        &:hover {
            background: rgba(150, 171, 165, 0.5);
            filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#5096aba5,endColorstr=#5096aba5);
        }   
    }
```

`.name` is an `anchor` element.

When I place my mouse on a `.name`, the `:hover` rules only apply when the cursor is on the border, but nothing happens when the cursor goes inside the element.

But when I set a `background-color: red` to the element, `:hover` become available again.

What may be the problem here?

Comment: I think a keyword would be "transparency" ..? Also, I've never seen that nested-CSS before :(

Comment: @pst I'm sorry. I forgot to explain the syntax, that's because I'm using `sass`.

Comment: (It might be useful to also include the plain-generated CSS :-)

Comment: It probably helps to make sure the element gets a "layout", using `zoom: 1;`

Comment: I've created fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/xbcPR/) and tried to fix the issue. I've made background w/o alpha and it seems to work. Please fork this fiddle if you find some inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Also use `background-image: url("about:blank");`

This should resolve the issue